# Is it possible to align initializer lists with clang-format?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I recently set up clang-format so that I can easily format my c++ code in a simple and consistent manner. However, I usually like to leave a space between the identifier and the initializer list, but also align subsequent variable declarations, as such:

```
std::string short       {"Hi!"};
std::string quite_long  {"Hi!"};
std::string even_longer {"Hi!"};
```

and clang-format automatically moves them back, immediately next to the identifier:

```
std::string short{"Hi!"}
```

Does anyone know if there is any way to make clang-format align initializer lists?

I tried to go through all the possible [options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) (and indeed search for the answer), but I simply didn't find anything, and was wondering if I have missed something. Since initialization with = is aligned I can use the following initialization method to achieve what I want in the mean time:

```
type identifier = {arguments};
```

but I would love to be able to be able to initialize normally.

Comment: note that such intendation style is usually discouraged because once you use version control system, adding a line `std::string even_more_longer {"Hi!"};` will cause unrelated lines to change making it hard to keep track of what acutally has been modified

Comment: I often like to align things also.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Swings and roundabouts.  'Pretty' code tends to be easier to read.